# How to compile a NASM file in Yocto?

Tags: assembly, nasm, yocto

I'm very new to Yocto. I want to compile a basic assembly code in NASM in Yocto. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: using sdk or make a recipe?

Comment: It will probably need something like `DEPENDS = "nasm-native"`?

Comment: By making recipes